# remove label of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible on JS to remove a label of a menu? I want to remove the text on the anchor menu without changing anything on the html. In replace of removing the menu I will add a new label via CSS using pseudo element before.

HTML:

```
<div class="navlink">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item active"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/skills/">Skills</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/project/">Project</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navlink li a:before { content:'1'; }
```

I think using CSS can achieve this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1yq59r7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS only.

HTML:

```
<div class="navlink">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item active"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/skills/">Skills</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/project/">Project</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://michaelpon.tk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navlink li a:before { content:'1'; visibility: visible; }
.navlink li a { content: ''; visibility: hidden; }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x1yq59r7/1/)